# Date format in Ms Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula

I have a large data set in MS Excel. My dates are in this format:

`06/05/2013` - `(mm/dd/YYYY)`

I need it to be

`6/5/2013` - `(m/d/YYYY)`

When I check "format cells" it shows "Date" but the values are not changing to "Number"
or to "General" or to anything else.  It only changes formats when it is 6/5/2013, not
06/06/2013. In the future I need my data set to be changed from Date to Number format.

So my question -

- How do I change large data set from 06/05/2011 for instance...to 6/5/2011.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is stored as a string, you should be able to make use of the `DateValue` function.

For example, if `A1` contains a string `06/05/2011` which is unaffected by changes to the Number Format of cell properties, you can do this in another cell:

`=DateValue(A1)` which will return the long date value.

[image: Before formatting]

This cell can then be formatted as a date.

[image: After formatting]

Finally, you can copy & paste values back over the original cells, and remove the helper column with the `DateValue` function.

Comment: To: David Zemens -  Thank you VERY MUCH ! It worked!

Comment: Cheers. Please consider "accepting" the answer if it's resolved your problem :)